# stress package not available on aws EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I am getting the package not available if I try to install stress package.

```
sudo yum install stress
```

Instance is connected to internet as I can run updates successfully. As I am trying out auto-scaling , is there any other way to do it. I have setup instance using Terraform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need amazon extra repository first. Use the following

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum install stress -y
```